# What is the lax colimit of an identity 2-functor?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

Recall that if $C$ is a category, then the identity functor $Id_C : C \to C$ has a colimit if and only if $C$ has a terminal object $1_C$, and in this case $\varinjlim Id_C = 1_C$.

**Question:** Now let $C$ be a 2-category. What is the lax colimit of the identity 2-functor $Id_C : C \to C$?

For $c \in C$, a morphism $\phi: laxcolim (Id_C) \to c$ should correspond to a [lax natural transformation](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/lax+natural+transformation) $\phi : Id_C \to const_c$. Such a lax natural transformation seems to encode a lot of data -- it yields a nonunital comonad structure on $c$, along with coalgebra structures on the 1-cells $\phi_x : x \to c$, such that every morphism $x \to y$ lifts functorially to a morphism of coalgebras. But the higher coherences satisfied by this data are sufficiently confusing that I'm hoping somebody has maybe thought about this before?

Comment: Would you be ok also knowing what's the lax bicolimit of id? (Not that I know the answer to that one either... are they equivalent by the way?)

Comment: @fosco sure— I don’t know if they’re the same, I’d be happy to know either